# Why doesn't .collect() work in the following GString?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, gstring

This works as expected in a GSP-page:

```
<td>${Foo.findAllByBar(bar)}</td>
```

But when adding a collect statement the code breaks ..

```
<td>${Foo.findAllByBar(bar).collect { it.name }}</td>
```

with

```
Error 500: Could not parse script [...gsp]: startup failed,
     ...: 129: expecting '}', found ')'
     @ line 129, column 196. 1 error`.
```

I was under the impression that any valid Groovy code could be placed in a GString `${ ... }` and being correctly evaluated/expanded. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GSP parser doesn't like `}` within the `${...}` block. Try this one:

```
<%= Foo.findAllByBar(bar).collect { it.name } %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Using <%= ... %> solved the problem. Is this a bug or is it by design?

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use the [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator%28.%29):

```
<td>${Foo.findAllByBar(bar)*.name}</td>
```